# Playing both to headphones and front

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, audio-jack

It is a simple question but what I found on Internet does not work. I have Ubuntu 18.04 and want to play audio simultaneously to front on the laptop(asus zenbook) and to headphones. Pulseaudio doesnt work because it shows only one device when I insert headphones. How can I do it? It worked on Windows so I dont think it is because of hardware. Thanks in advance

Comment: It will not work because of [hardware switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#Switch_contacts) inside 3.5 mm jack (female part in laptop) ...

Comment: @N0rbert OP (explicitly) says it worked in Windows.